# MS SQL Server - Search keywords and aggregate count on Vendors

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have two tables and want to search software table based on the keywords stored in Vendor table and show aggregate value. Can this be achieved without looping the data. No relationship exists between these tables. Let us assume I do not know software belong to which vendor. Only source i have is keywords to relate.

```
Vendors table
vID       Name        keywords
---------------------------------
 1        Microsoft   Windows
 1        Microsoft   Visual Studio
 2        Oracle      Java
 3        Red Hat     Linux

Softwares
sID        Title
---------------------------------
 1       Windows 2012 R2
 2       Microsoft Visual Studio
 3       Microsoft Xml 4.0
 4       Linux version 11
```

Result:

```
Vendor Name   Counts
-----------------------
Microsoft     3
Oracle        0
Red Hat       1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
Select v.name as [Vendor Name], count(*) as Counts
from Vendors v, Softwares s 
where charindex(v.name, s.title) >0
group by v.name
```

Comment: also add this to the where clause `OR charindex(v.keywords,s.title) > 0` and I would use explicit CROSS JOIN syntax.

Comment: Good catch, I posted too fast.